# SwiftUI `navigationBarItems` vs `toolbar` what are the differences?

Tags: swift, swiftui

What are the differences between `navigationBarItems` vs `toolbar` in SwiftUI? I've been using them interchangeably and feel like they are doing the same things with different syntax, eg: put buttons on navigationBar (.leading/.trailing).

Comment: The most important one is navigationBarItems is being deprecated and everybody will have to migrate to .toolbar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned by Lorem Ipsum, `.toolbar` is the way to go forward. The biggest difference is that `.navigationBarItems` is iOS/iPad OS only, whereas `.toolbar` works on macOS as well.

This makes it much easier to create universal views.

If you're just targeting mobile devices, there isn't really any difference in outcome at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

.toolbar will (by default) automatically display the button on the leading or trailing edge depending on the locale.

```
.toolbar{
    Button("Edit") {
        print("Editing ...")
    }
}
```

This will show the button on the trailing edge for left- to-right languages, or on the leading edge for right-to-left. You can put it where you want by wrapping it in a `ToolbarItem()`.

```
.toolbar{
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        // Button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said: `.toolbar` requires iOS 14.
A lots of projects need to be backward-compatible to iOS 13 and then `navigationBarItems` is the only way to achieve this